# Can I join spheres together and remesh them in a way that keeps the shaders?

Tags: mesh, uv, shaders, smooth, remesh

[image: Blender remeshing but keep shading]

I want to "weld" the edges of the spheres together, but at the same time keeping the colors.
I'm going to have way more spheres, so assigning the shaders manually will be too much work.

I tried looking into doing it in Geometry nodes instead, but it seems that it will still loose the shading information.

Comment: Don't use multiple materials - this way you're setting yourself up for jagged sudden edges, whereas remeshing seems to be done specifically to smoothen them. So use a single material, but capture a color attribute. Then after remeshing you can data transfer the attribute by nearest, and you can smooth the attribute.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thank you, what I'm doing is downloading molecule models that already have some basic shading assigned. If I use color attribute will I then have to manually paint the areas that should contain each color?

Comment: No, the idea is that instead of having multiple materials (one per color) you have one material, that reads color from attribute. The attribute could be a vertex color for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using **Geometry Nodes**:

1. Put all your Spheres with different materials in a Collection "*Spheres*"

[image]

2. Create a **Plane** object outside the collection. Name it "Remesh". Add the **Geometry Node** modifier (*set up bellow*). Then Add the **Remesh** modifier

[image]

3. Create another **Plane** object outside the collection. Name it "Material". Add the **Geometry Node** modifier (*set up bellow*).

[image]

You can now apply the Geometry Node modifier and get a mesh with all materials applied to it.

**EDIT**: Here is a most recent .blend file (naming may slightly differ)

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant! Just what i needed thank you!

Comment: Actually for some reason it only ends up with one of the shaders?
https://imgur.com/a/8V1ObMb

Comment: It is possible that you are not following the steps correctly. Double check the nodes and how they are connected (your screenshot shows a missed connection to the Material Index). I have added a blend file in my answer that you can study.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right, sorry about that. Thank you for your help!